# QuickGraph BreadthFirstSearch

Tags: c#, quickgraph

I am using QuickGraph library and I need a method to get the distance or the route from a vertex to itself.
My graph is a Directed and weighted also it can be cyclic. I have read that I need to use bfs but I could not see any implementation for BFS for this.

Do you have any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:
There is a BFS algorithm in QuickGraph, see here:
https://github.com/rhishi/QuickGraph/blob/master/3.0/sources/QuickGraph/Algorithms/Search/BreadthFirstSearchAlgorithm.cs

and a unit test:
https://github.com/rhishi/QuickGraph/blob/master/3.0/sources/QuickGraph.Tests/Algorithms/Search/BreadthFirstSearchAlgirthmTest.cs